# Python Compound Interest Not Working

Tags: python, calculator, python-3.6

Here's what I have so far, I think it's complete and I have zero errors other than the fact that the output is just 10,000 (which is way wrong, I've been using 15 years as "t"). I've looked around at similar questions and followed a few of the suggestions but nothing has fixed it. Is there just something silly I'm missing? Thanks!

```
print ("Hello, this program will calculate compound interest with a rate of 8%, a principal of 10,000 dollars, on a 12 month cycle (where n is 12)")
p = 10000.00
r = .08
n = 12
t = int(input("Please enter the length of time for the interest to be compounded: "))
amount = (p*(1+(r//(100.0*n))**(n*t)))
print ("The final amount is",amount,"for an initial investment of 10,000, with a rate of 8% and compounded monthly over",t,"years.")
```

Comment: `0.08//(100.0*12) == 0`. `//` is explicit floor division; see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations.

Comment: switched it to single slash and seems to be having the same error.

Comment: It does work as mentioned by @jonrsharpe: ((1+(r/(100*n)))**(n*t)). Is this the answer 10120.718840552334? You have messed up on the brackets. Try evaluating parts first rather than the whole expression. Start with (1+r/n). Evaluate using a calculator if you've put the right equation or messed up on the brackets.

Comment: Ah I found the bracket error. Thank you for your help! everything looks correct now.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, your code doesn't capture the actual formula very well. Check the brackets properly.

```
print ("Hello, this program will calculate compound interest with a rate of 8%, a     principal of 10,000 dollars, on a 12 month cycle (where n is 12)")
p = 10000.00
r = .08
n = 12
t = int(input("Please enter the length of time for the interest to be compounded: "))
amount = p*((1+(r/(100*n)))**(n*t))
print ("The final amount is",amount,"for an initial investment of 10,000, with a rate of 8% and compounded monthly over",t,"years.")
```

Result: 10120.718840552334